# One sided Wald test

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I want to construct the following hypothesis test:

$$H_0: \theta < \theta_0 \  \mathrm{vs.} \ H_1: \theta \geq \theta_0.$$

My idea was that the one-sided Wald test is equivalent to testing whether $\theta_0$ is contained in the following confidence interval (if not then reject the null hypothesis):

$$(-\infty,\hat{\theta} - z_{\alpha} \hat{\mathrm{se}}(\hat{\theta}))$$

but I am not sure whether this makes sense. And by the way, $\theta$ is the Binomial parameter $p$ so $\theta \in [0,1]$.

Comment: What kind of data? What is $\theta?$

Comment: $X_1,...,X_n$ is iid Binomial and $\theta=p$

Comment: (1) Null hypothesis must have an equal sign $=, \le,$ or $\ge$ so it needs to be $H_0: \theta \le \theta_0$ vs $H_a: \theta > \theta_0.$ (2) If $p \in [0,1],$ then why do you suggest CI with lower limit $-\infty ?$ (3) For small $n$ Wald CI is not a true inversion of corresponding test.